# Rounded edges on menu items in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: My navbar]

I am trying to round the edges on my navbar. I ended up adding a border radius to every item in the hierarchy, but it still does not work. All the edges are sharp. How do I fix this?

Markup:

```
 <div id="menystrip" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div id="menutitems" class="container">
            <div id="menustrip" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul id="menustripul" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li id="menuitemtoday" class="active"><a href="/">Idag</a></li>
                    <li id="menuitemtomorrow" class=""><a href="/Movies/MoviesTomorrow">Imorgon</a></li>
                    <li id="menuitemdayaftertomorrow" class=""><a href="/Movies/MoviesTheDayAfterTomorrow">P&#229; tisdag</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#menustrip {
    border-radius:15px;
}

#menustripul {
   border-radius: 15px;
}

#menutitems {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#menuitemtoday {
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

#menuitemdayaftertomorrow {
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

Edit: This is what style every item gets when I use the dev tools in chrome, please note that the bottom three are overridden (a dash shrough them):

```
#menutitems {
    padding-top: 15px !important;
    padding-bottom: 15px !important;
    border-radius: 15px !important;
}
#menutitems {
    padding-top: 15px !important;
    padding-bottom: 15px !important;
    border-radius: 15px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the background colour on the `a` as it obscures the border on the `li`. Remove it and set the colour on the `li` and it looks fine.

```css
.navbar-inverse #menustripul li.active {
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar-inverse #menustripul li.active a {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#menustrip {
    border-radius:15px;
}

#menustripul {
   border-radius: 15px;
}

#menutitems {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#menuitemtoday {
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

#menuitemdayaftertomorrow {
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <div id="menystrip" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div id="menutitems" class="container">
            <div id="menustrip" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul id="menustripul" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li id="menuitemtoday" class="active"><a href="/">Idag</a></li>
                    <li id="menuitemtomorrow" class=""><a href="/Movies/MoviesTomorrow">Imorgon</a></li>
                    <li id="menuitemdayaftertomorrow" class=""><a href="/Movies/MoviesTheDayAfterTomorrow">P&#229; tisdag</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In rendered page(e.g. via chrome dev tools) check if something is overriding your styles. If that is the case try including your stylesheet after every other or/and adding `!important` at the end of your rules(e.g. `border-radius: 15px !important;`).

Comment: You should almost never recommend to use `!important`, instead fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want only `border-radius` for first and last element use this css:

```
#menustripul > li:first-child > a{
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}
#menustripul > li:last-child > a{
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

or if you want for every menu item:

```
#menustripul > li > a{
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/twjo6kjf/)

Comment: But the thing is that now I put it on every single item and it still does not work. I was thinking that maybe the stylesheet is not read, but like I write in the Edit, the elements actualy gets the border radius. WTF?

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap 4.X supports classes for [rounding an element](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/borders/). Add **rounded** class to round menu items.

```
<div id="menystrip" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div id="menutitems" class="container">
        <div id="menustrip" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul id="menustripul" class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li id="menuitemtoday" class="active"><a class="rounded" href="/">Idag</a></li>
                <li id="menuitemtomorrow" class=""><a class="rounded" href="/Movies/MoviesTomorrow">Imorgon</a></li>
                <li id="menuitemdayaftertomorrow" class=""><a class="rounded" href="/Movies/MoviesTheDayAfterTomorrow">P&#229; tisdag</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```